# Cloning BitBucket repo using password in git clone command causes issue

Tags: git, azure, bitbucket, bitbucket-cloud

I am trying to use the password in my `git clone` command to clone the repo but it always ends up with this error:

```
remote: Login failed due to incorrect login credentials or method.
remote: If you are unsure of which login details or login method to use, visit:
remote: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/log-into-or-connect-to-bitbucket-cloud/
fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://bitbucket.org/qhluo123/ceye-admin.git/'
```

Here is my clone command:

```
git clone http://username:password@bitbucket.org/qhluo123/ceye-admin.git
```

I can not use ssh or the pop-up method for the password as I am working on automatically cloning and deploying the repo on a remote system. None of the inputs are possible by the user side during the process. Is there any way I could solve this issue?

Adding SSH is not a solution as I am deploying it in the ARM template for Microsoft and the ARM template always creates a new VM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use an [HTTPS access token](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/http-access-tokens-939515499.html) instead of your account password.

Most remote Git repository hosting services (GitHub, GitLab, Bitbucket) use tokens as password.

It is also best to use a [Git Credential helper](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials), like, as [per Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/set-up-credential-managers?view=azure-devops), the [Git Credential Manager](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager) which comes with [Git For Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases).
That way, you do not have to use in plain-text URL your token.

In your case, since the clone is don on a remote deploy ARM server, that might not apply, but using a token instead of a password remains the recommended option.

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue was resolved by creating an 'App password' on Bitbucket - top right corner Settings -> Personal Bibucket settings -> App passwords -> Create app password.